# how can i get sum of all amounts requested - mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on an HRM project using MERN stack I have a medical expense section in which employees can request expense coverage (limit = 6000), how can I **sum** all requested **amounts** by **employee** and check if each employee is exceeding the limit before requesting here is my code:-

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // check if employee has pending  request 
  let medicalExpenseRequest = await MedicalExpenseRequest.findOne({
    "employee._id": req.body.employeeId,
    "medicalExpense._id": req.body.medicalExpenseId,
    status: "Pending",
  });
  if (medicalExpenseRequest)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send("Oops there is pending medical request for this employee!");
  // this blocks the employee to request more than the limit at once // medicalexpense.allowed == 6000
  if (req.body.amount > medicalExpense.allowedAmount)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(
        `Sorry can't request more than ${medicalExpense.allowedAmount} ETB`
      );

  // keep track of each employee request 
//I want to check if the sum of all amounts requested by employee is greater than the limit and block if it is true
  let taken;

  const coveredExpense = await MedicalExpenseRequest.aggregate([
    // { $match: { _id: { $eq: req.body.employeeId } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$employee._id",
        totalTaken: { $sum: "$amount" },
      },
    },
  ]);
  

  // process the request successfully

});
```

**NB:** I tried MongoDB aggregates but I could not able to achieve the target

Comment: You can add a new stage, after the `$group`, to check if the `totalTaken` exceeds the limit (`allowedAmount`).

Comment: hey thanks, prasad can you show me the new stage implementation please ?

Comment: Please give it a try and post if there are any issues. A `$project` (or `$addFields`) stage with a [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) aggregation comparison operation will return a _boolean_ - this will tell if amount  exceeds or not.

Comment: ok thanks i will try and let you know the outcome

Comment: thanks sir i figured out and posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out by my self what i did is to filter through `coveredExpense` and check if **taken amount** is greater than the allowed amount

```
 coveredExpense.filter((expense) => {
    taken = expense.totalTaken;
    emp_id = expense._id;
  });

  if (
    taken >= medicalExpense.allowedAmount &&
    medicalRequesEmployee &&
    medicalRequesEmployee.employee._id.equals(emp_id)
  ) {
    return res.status(400).send("You have exceeded the limit");
  }
```